# Azure Storage Files read only access - what permissions should I give?

Tags: permissions, azure, azure-storage

I'm trying to give my team mate an access to backups kept on Azure Storage Files.

I gave him a `Reader` for a Resource Group and a 
`Storage File Data SMB Share Reader` for File Share resource. He's getting Access Denied (to perform `listKey` action). What did I missed?

(It works when I'm giving `Contributor` but it's to much of course.)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The RBAC permissions you are granting giving the user access to manage the storage account, not to get to the data.

Granting permission to access the data is not done using RBAC. If you want to grant read only access then you would want to generate a SAS token for the account, container or blob you are interested in and set permissions to read.